# VPN into company office to view website

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to move my morning remote office to a coffee shop. The website we are working on at the moment requires my IP address be added in the `apache configurations`. I know we have VPN (which ive only used sparingly). If i log into VPN (openVPN) from a coffee shop can i access the website without having to use the coffee shop IP added into `apache`? Im currently just at an IP that has the IP stored, no VPN

Comment: why downvote? its a legitimate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a VPN connection will use the VPN server IP address when making a request to another server.  You could use that IP to whitelist your computer from any other IP address you can access the VPN from.

Comment: Yes.  That that is the basic functionality of a VPN.  You mask your original IP and use the VPN server IP.

Comment: awesome thanks ill mark this answer in 10 min\